# Read header of PPM file only using getchar()

Tags: c, function, getchar, ppm

I need to read a PPM file but I'm limited to only using getchar() but I'm running into trouble ignoring whitespaces.

I'm using `num=num*10+(ch-48);` to read the height and width but don't know how to read them all at once while ignoring spaces and '\n' or comments.

I use this to read the magic number:

```
int magic;
while(magic==0){
if (getchar()=='P')     //MAGIC NUMBER
magic=getchar()-48;
}
printf("%d\\n",magic);
```

i used this function to read the height and width which works only when the data in the header is seperated only by `'\n'`

```
int getinteger(int base)
{ char ch;
int val = 0;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\\n' && (ch = getchar()) != '\\t' && (ch = getchar()) != ' ')
if (ch \>= '0' && ch \<= '0'+base-1)
val = base\*val + (ch-'0');
else
return ERROR;
return val;
}
```

this is the part in main()

```
height=getinteger(10);
    while(height==-1){
        height=getinteger(10);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Does your compiler mention something about multi-character literals when it sees `'\\n'`? Why do you escape the backshlash?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing "magic" with 0 is undefined behaviour since it's not initialized yet (so it's basically just a chunk of memory):

```c
int magic;              // WARNING: We don't know exact value, may be not 0
while(magic==0){
if (getchar()=='P')     //MAGIC NUMBER
magic=getchar()-48;
}
```

Consider initializing variable before comparing:

```c
int magic = 0;            // We know that magic will be defined as 0
while (magic == 0) {
    if (getchar() == 'P') // MAGIC NUMBER
        magic = getchar() - 48;
}
```

In this function:

```c
int getinteger(int base)
{ char ch;
int val = 0;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\\n' && (ch = getchar()) != '\\t' && (ch = getchar()) != ' ')
if (ch \>= '0' && ch \<= '0'+base-1)
val = base\*val + (ch-'0');
else
return ERROR;
return val;
}
```

(I'm assuming that ERROR = -1, is that correct?) In your condition `getchar()` will work 3 times, not 1 (since it calls `getchar()` for putting in `ch` every check). Rewrite it to call only once for saving in variable `ch`. Another problem occurs when first symbol will be whitespace, not digit. In this case `val` will remains `0` (since `while` loop will be skipped), so returned value will also be '0'. To avoid this, you can check value of `val` and return ERROR, when it is not changed:

```c
int getinteger(int base) {
    char ch = getchar(); // get only one char and save for later use
    int val = 0; // 0 means not changed
    while (ch != '\n' && ch != '\t' && ch != ' ') {
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '0' + base - 1)
            val = base * val + (ch - '0');
        else
            return ERROR;
        ch = getchar(); // get a new char for next loop iteration and checking if it is digit
    }
    if (val == 0) // val was not changed
            return ERROR; // loop in "main" will be continued
    else
            return val; // val was changed, return it
}
```

UPD: We can also use this fact to simplify our function a lot:

```c
int getinteger(int base) {
    char ch = getchar(); // get only one char and save for later use
    int val = 0; // 0" means not changed
    while (ch >= '0' && ch <= '0' + base - 1) { // if "ch" is not a number, this loop will be skipped
            val = base * val + (ch - '0');
            ch = getchar(); // get a new char for next loop iteration and checking if it is digit
    }

    if (val == 0) // val was not changed (ch was not a number)
        return ERROR; // loop in "main" will be continued
    else
        return val; // val was changed, return it
}
```

And last but not least, remove extra '' before symbols (`\\n` -> `\n`, `\>=` -> `>=` etc.) if they present in your code.

Combining everything above results in something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ERROR -1

int getinteger(int base) {
    char ch = getchar(); // get only one char and save for later use
    int val = 0; // 0 means not changed
    while (ch >= '0' && ch <= '0' + base - 1) { // if "ch" is not a number, this loop will be skipped
            val = base * val + (ch - '0');
            ch = getchar(); // get a new char for next loop iteration and checking if it is digit
    }

    if (val == 0) // val was not changed (ch was not a number)
        return ERROR; // loop in "main" will be continued
    else
        return val; // val was changed, return it
}

int main() {
    // dunno what's before
    int magic = 0; // We know that magic will be defined as 0
    while (magic == 0) {
        if (getchar() == 'P') // MAGIC NUMBER
            magic = getchar() - 48;
    }
    printf("magic = %d\n", magic);

    int height = getinteger(10);
    while (height == -1)
        height = getinteger(10);
    printf("height = %d\n", height);
    // dunno what's after
}
```

Result:

```bash
$ echo "   \n  P3 #blabla \n  34  \t " | ./a.out
magic = 3
height = 34
```